# Numpy array indexing: view or copy - depends on scope?

Tags: python, numpy, scope, pass-by-reference, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following array manipulations:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
     x += 1
x = np.zeros(1)
f(x)       # changes `x`
f(x[0])    # doesn't change `x`
x[0] += 1  # changes `x`
```

Why does `x[0]` behave differently depending on whether `+= 1` happens inside or outside the function `f`?

Can I pass a part of the array to the function, such that the function modifies the original array?

---

Edit: If we considered `=` instead of `+=`, we would probably maintain the core of the question while getting rid of some irrelevant complexity.

Comment: becasue wehn you pass x[0] , you are just passing that value ( as an object) not the whole x object

Comment: @eshirvana If the *passing* makes a copy, why does `f(x)` modify `x`? If the *indexing* makes a copy, why does `x[0] += 1` modify the original? If *passing* makes a copy only if there was *indexing*, how does passing know whether there was indexing or not, and why was this dependency implemented?

Comment: `x` is mutable, `x[0]` is not. It means `__iadd__` can modify x but not `x[0]`. This is not really about indexing. If `x[0]` were mutable and had an `__iadd__` method defined to modify it in place, that would change too. Try it with a two dimensional array and you will see that passing `x[0]` will change its first row.

Comment: @ayhan If `x[0]` is not mutable and `__iadd__` (same as `+=`?) cannot modify it, then why does `x[0]+=1` modify it? Also, why does Python consider `x[0]` not mutable even though it is possible to modify it directly (by modifying the first entry of `x`)?

Comment: Yes, `__iadd__` is `+=`. When you do `x[0] = 1` or `x[0] = x[0] + 1` or `x[0] += 1`, and x[0] is an integer, you are not really modifying the integer there but instead pointing it to a different integer. Ned Batchelder has a great [article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) about this.

Comment: @root *passing never makes a copy*. When you *index into a numpy array*, a *entirely new object* is created. Check what happens if you do `x[0] is x[0]`. If `x[0]` is a scalar value, it won't modify the original at all

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why does `x[0] += 1` change the array, even though it accesses the array `x` only by indexing, and you write "When you *index into a numpy array*, a *entirely new object* is created"? Probably because there are two different kinds of indexing: `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (the latter is when the indexing happens on the left of an equals sign, so to speak), as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444042/5231110).

Comment: @root yes, that's it. `__getitem__` returns a new object, `__setitem__` mutates the underlying buffer... You have to understand these are basically just sugar for calls to methods. They can, in principle, do *anything* and they don't have to be consistent with each other

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The fact that they don't have to be consistent with each other is very interesting and not necessarily expected/intuitive. Are there articles with nice examples?

Comment: @root just *implement a class* with both and see for youreslf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not scope, since the only thing that depends on scope is the available names. All objects can be accessed in any scope that has a name for them. The issue is one of mutability vs immutability and understanding what operators do.

`x` is a mutable numpy array. `f` runs `x += 1` directly on it. `+=` is the operator that invokes in-place addition. In other words, it does [`x = x.__iadd__(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)<sup>*</sup>. Notice the reassignment to `x`, which happens in the function. That is a feature of the in-place operators that allows them to operate on immutable objects. In this case, [`ndarray.__iadd__`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__iadd__.html) is a true in-place operator which just returns `x`, and everything works as expected.

Now let's analyze `f(x[0])` the same way. `x[0]` calls [`x.__getitem__(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)<sup>*</sup>. When you pass in a scalar `int` index, numpy extracts a one-element array and effectively calls [`.item()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) on it. The result is a python `int` (or `float`, or even possibly a `tuple`, depending on what your array's `dtype` is). Either way, the object is immutable. Once it's been extracted by `__getitem__`, the `+=` operator in `f` replaces the name `x` **in `f`** with the new object, but the change is not seen outside the function, much less in the array. In this scenario, `f` has no reference to `x`, so no change is to be expected.

The example of `x[0] += 1` is not the same as calling `f(x[0])`. It is equivalent to calling [`x.__setitem__(0, x.__getitem__(0).__iadd__(1))`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)<sup>*</sup>. The call to `f` was only the part with `type(x).__getitem__(0).__iadd__(1)`, which returns a new object, but never reassigns as `__setitem__` does. **The key is that `[] =` (`__setitem__`) in python is an entirely different operator from `[]` (`__getitem__`) and `=` (assingment) separately**.

To make the second example (`f(x[0]`) work, you would have to pass in a mutable object. An integer object extracts a single python object, and an array index makes a copy. However, a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) index returns a view that is mutable and tied to the original array memory. Therefore, you can do

```
f(x[0:1])  # changes `x`
```

In this case `f` does the following: `x.__getitem__(slice(0, 1, None)).__iadd__(1)`. The key is that `__getitem__` returns a mutable view into the original array, not an immutable `int`.

To see why it is important not only that the object is mutable but that it is a view into the original array, try `f(x[[0]])`. Indexing with a list produces an array, but a copy. In `x[[0]].__iadd__` will modify the list you pass in in-place, but the list is not copied back into the original, so the change will not propagate.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is an approximation. When invoked by an operator, dunder methods are actually called as `type(x).__operator__(x, ...)`, not `x.__operator__(...)`.

Comment: You write "The key is that `[] =` (`__setitem__`) in python is an entirely different operator from `[]` (`__getitem__`) and `=` (assingment) separately." Do you recall a nice explanation of this, for example in the Python documentation?

Comment: This sentence is important, please make it bold in the answer: "The key is that `[] =` (`__setitem__`) in python is an entirely different operator from `[]` (`__getitem__`) and `=` (assingment) separately." (I can't suggest an edit because the suggested-edit queue is full.) Thanks! :)

Comment: @root. That's just the definition of the method and my personal interpretation. This insight was very helpful to me when I was first learning, so I'm happy to bold it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the function call to see this difference.

`x` is an array:

```
In [138]: type(x)
Out[138]: numpy.ndarray
```

Indexing an element of the array returns a `np.float64` object.  It in effect "takes" the value out of the array; it is not a reference to the element of the array.

```
In [140]: y=x[0]
In [141]: type(y)
Out[141]: numpy.float64
```

This `y` is a lot like a python float; you can `+=` the same way:

```
In [142]: y += 1
In [143]: y
Out[143]: 1.0
```

but this does not change `x`:

```
In [144]: x
Out[144]: array([0.])
```

But this does change `x`:

```
In [145]: x[0] += 1
In [146]: x
Out[146]: array([1.])
```

`y=x[0]` does a `x.__getitem__` call.  `x[0]=3` does a `x.__setitem__` call.  `+=` uses `__iadd__`, but it's similar in effect.

Another example:

Changing `x`:

```
In [149]: x[0] = 3
In [150]: x
Out[150]: array([3.])
```

but attempting to do the same to `y` fails:

```
In [151]: y[()] = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-151-153d89268cbc>", line 1, in <module>
    y[()] = 3
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

but `y[()]` is allowed.

`basic` indexing of an array with a slice does produce a `view` that can be modified:

```
In [154]: x = np.zeros(5)
In [155]: x
Out[155]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
In [156]: y= x[0:2]
In [157]: type(y)
Out[157]: numpy.ndarray
In [158]: y += 1
In [159]: y
Out[159]: array([1., 1.])
In [160]: x
Out[160]: array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
```

===

Python list and dict examples of the `x[0]+=1` kind of action:

```
In [405]: alist = [1,2,3]
In [406]: alist[1]+=12
In [407]: alist
Out[407]: [1, 14, 3]
In [408]: adict = {'a':32}
In [409]: adict['a'] += 12
In [410]: adict
Out[410]: {'a': 44}
```

`__iadd__` can be thought of a `__getitem__` followed by a `__setitem__` with the same index.

Comment: Why does `x[0] += 1` change the array, even though it accesses the array `x` only by indexing, and you write that indexing "'takes' the value out of the array; it is not a reference to the element of the array"? Probably because there are two different kinds of indexing `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (the latter is when the indexing happens on the left of an equals sign, so to speak), as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444042/5231110).

Comment: This `+=` action isn't unique to arrays.  I added examples with list and dict.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441552/numpy-array-indexing-view-or-copy-depends-on-scope/70442585?noredirect=1#comment124593322_70441552) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444042/5231110):

- The `x[0]` inside of `f(x[0])` performs `__getitem__` on `x`. In this particular case (as opposed to indexing a *slice* of the array, for example), the value returned by this operation doesn't allow modifying the original array.
- `x[0] = 1` performs `__setitem__` on `x`.

`__getitem__` and `__setitem__` can be defined/overloaded to do anything. They don't even have to be consistent with each other.